# How do I add milestones to an already existing timeline chart in excel

Tags: charts, excel-charts

I have the data of temperatures over the past century with me.

[data extracted from here](https://data.giss.nasa.gov/gistemp/graphs/graph_data/Global_Mean_Estimates_based_on_Land_and_Ocean_Data/graph.txt)

[google sheet with the requisite data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1w2V1BAZ0D0O8lqCm0XKws-9ZOuXthxhxnlCImWyNdKk/edit?usp=sharing)

I have this data that shows the important events over the centuries.
(milestones)

year    reason

1712    Steam Engine Invented; Start of industrialisation

1824    Greenhouse Concept described by "J Fourier"

1886    Karl Benz designed first Automobile

1969    UNESCO Conference "Earth Day is born"

1972    First UN environment conference. The United Nations Environment Programme (UNEP) is formed.

1980    The Vienna Convention for protection of Ozone layer (1985) ; Montreal Porocol (1987)

1997    Kyoto Protocol Signed

Now when i created the chart using just the above data, i get

[TimeLine chart that is formed](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vTXuq_cCJlyFQNCrVXNpla4zE5Ok3PBmkX05uUQ8hmtiT2Nxd4Aw4qDpI8GvnIhrKYIVVkRHe1GdtZV/pubchart?oid=2097008615&format=interactive)

I want to add the additional data of the important events to the same chart.

I checked the milestones chart but did not work for me.

Comment: Hi! This question is very vague. From reading your description, it's not clear what "milestones" and "existing timeline charts" are. Could you please specify more information? Ideally your question contains all information relevant without the need to click on a link or download files from an external site. You may also include screenshots if that helps other readers.

Comment: I have updated the data to make it more clear.